# existing virtualbox machine exported using vagramt but I can't use it

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I had an existing opensuse 64 bit machine which i exported using

vagrant package --base opensuse64 --output opensuse.box

After creating box I created another folder 'package-test' and copied the created box file there. Then I used

vagrant init opensuse opensuse.box

and then

vagrant up

but I am unable to connect to it via ssh.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output `VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant ssh`. Have you configured the OpenSUSE VM for Public Key Authentication using Vagrant's key pair?

Comment: That explains it. I thought I can use putty to ssh with existing user and key pair. Is there any option in vagrantfile to set existing user/pass and ssh key pair to be used by vagrant when vagrant up command is used?

Comment: I'll add an answer anyway, comment sucks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `vagrant ssh` work, your OpenSUSE VM has to be configured for Public Key Authentication using Vagrant's key pair.

If you want to use password authentication, you'll have to specify the ssh port and use username/password known to you.

> NOTE: If this is a vagrant base box, by default you can login as vagrant/vagrant with `sudo` privilege, as per the packaging guide.

If you want to use your own key pair, you can copy the public key and add it to the VM's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Examples

Manual (1 liner)

```sh
cat /path/to/vagrant.pub | ssh user@host 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Use `ssh-copy-id`

```sh
# -i defaults to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-copy-id user@host

# custom pub key
ssh-copy-id -i vagrant.pub user@host
```

> NOTE: make sure `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the VM have proper permission.

Comment: I think something is wrong with virtualbox export command which vagrant use to package the box. After doing exactly what you said and also going through other guide about creating custom box, my machine gave same error again. Then I cloned as well as exported the existing VM using VBox interface. Both new machines boot into emergency mode when started via virtualbox. Also I could see same mode in preview window when I used vagrant up. I think it is virtualbox issue now and not vagrant. Thanks for help.